# Flask, Apache, CentOS, and Permission Denied on the datastore

Tags: apache, flask, file-permissions, permission-denied, berkeley-db

I've setup up a flask project on a CentOS 6.4 machine, with python 2.7.6 and mod_wsgi 3.x that I built myself on the box.

The app uses a file based database for storing RDF data, and I'm getting an Error 13 on the folder containing the datastore.

```
from genometry import app as application
File "/opt/genometry/software/genometry.py", line 125, in <module>
db, classes, user_datastore, security = create_db(app)
File "/opt/genometry/software/genometry.py", line 101, in create_db
db.store.open(app.config['db'])
"build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/rdflib/plugins/sleepycat.py", line 89, in open
db_env = self._init_db_environment(homeDir, create)
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/rdflib/plugins/sleepycat.py", line 66, in     _init_db_environment
mkdir(homeDir)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'store.kb'
```

I've tried everything I can think of.  Changed the /opt and everything under it to be owned by apache:apache.  Changed /opt and everything under it to be 777, and yet still a permissions error.  How can that be?  What's the best way to setup the permission on folder "store.kb"

Comment: start pdb with `strace -f`. This will display all the system calls. There's probably something else going on which throws the permission denied error.

Comment: @MichelMüller The app is running with wsgi script and mod_wsgi.  How can I start pdb?  I found this http://winpdb.org/docs/embedded-debugging/

Comment: Do you have access to the server's console? If not I'm sorry, I don't know mod_wsgi enough. If yes, use `python -m pdb [PATH-TO-APP].py`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was that Apache was looking for the store.kb in /var/www due to the rdfalchemy db uri.  I updated it to:

```
app.config['rdfalchemy_dburi'] = 'sleepycat:////{0}/store.kb'.format(PROJECT_ROOT)
```

and now everything works fine